# Does a two-port charger at 1.5A provide 750mA from each port?

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

So, I'm looking to buy this energizer charger: [http://www.amazon.com/Energizer-Dual-Universal-Charger-Pc2-wa/dp/B004YZI1VW/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004YZI1VW)

The 1 port product has 1A the two port product has 1.5A. Does that mean that I'll get 750mA from each port? Or if I only have one device plugged in I'll get 1.5mA max

Comment: I am using a locally found 5V 2.5A charger soldered at one end to an MicroUSB-B male. It costed me approx less than GBP £6 or USD $10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It only says *1.5Amp Total* in the specs. It doesn't say how that current gets shared between ports, but most likely it's just simply connected in parallel, which means that you could draw 750 mA from each port, or 1.5 A from  one port only. Or 1 A from one port and 0.5 A from the other. Any combination, as long as the total current doesn't exceed 1.5 A.

But all this is just (educated) guessing, as the Amazon page doesn't give the specifications too clearly.

Comment: Thanks. 750mA should suffice for my pi and my phone. Thanks